# Best-Practises to Store DNS Domains in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

ok, so I have been pondering this a while now, and it is not obvious - here is my attempt in SQL (for PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE domains (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  display_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  domain_name  varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  tld varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  domain_type  INT NOT NULL,
  --
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
```

but some questions would be:
* store the http:// - with the domain? - e.g. http://www.domain.com ?
* is it worth to break out the tld into it's own column? e.g. .com
* case? does this matter
* anything else?

What does everyone else do? - thanks,

Comment: "http" is not part of the domain, so I would say that storing that would be superfluous. As far as breaking apart the ".com", I think that is something that could be done at any time, should the need arise in the future. In other words, if you choose NOT to store it as a separate column, you could always parse it out using a simple regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there are no best practices to storing DNS entries.  There are best practices for how to store data in a database.  That is usually driven by reducing duplication of the stored data, and how that data will be accessed.

I find it's almost never productive to think about the structure of something without first going through how it's going to be used.

I would also consider what the cost is to doing a naive implementation and restructuring later.  Sometimes the cost is actually not that bad.  The cost can also be mitigated by considering it with the first implementation where you could set up additional mechanisms or do partial data break outs to reduce cost later.

Comment: actually that is a good idea - I was trying to avoid refactoring, but I suppose it is trying to design something and we cannot fully predict how it will grow in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind everything depends on your intended use.

You may want to keep the http:// but in a separate column or bit field.  You may decide you want to differentiate between ftp, http, https, etc.

The tld again depends on intended use.  Will there be a lot of international sites like bbc.co.uk with multiple tld listings?  You will probably want that separately because it may be an issue to separate that out.  Again, if you don't think you will be using just the tld for anything it may not matter.  It will be a lot easier to start it the right way than to change course partway through, though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact query needs, you can store URLs as a single field and simply use regular expressions to parse them and extract the necessary components.  Since URLs are specifically formatted for computers to decipher, parsing them with regular expressions is fairly foolproof.

Of course querying the data can be harder if you are searching for something specific, but that will need to inform your overall database design.